# Access MySQL table column using PHP (not by column name, but by column number)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code, it allows me to access the MySQL columns based on their names

```
 $sql = "SELECT age, name, sex  FROM info";
```

how can I change the code so it shows it from the column's number (not name) in the table

```
 $sql = "SELECT column1, column2, column3  FROM info";
```

Where:

- age is the first column in table called info
- name is the second column in table called info
- sex is the third column in table called info
- desc is the fourth column

That way if you do not know the column name, you can just do it by column number

The problem I am having is one of my column names is called "desc" (its column number 4)

So the code below will not work

```
 $sql = "SELECT age, name, sex, desc  FROM info";
```

if I ignore that column and just look at the first 3 columns, my php code will work fine

```
 $sql = "SELECT age, name, sex  FROM info";
```

Comment: If you dont know the columns name how are you going to be sure of the column order???????

Comment: And no you cannot do that, well not in that way anyway

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you trying to do this? What do you hope to accomplish?

Comment: the problem I have is that one of my column names is "desc" but when I put the word "desc" in the code, the code stops the work, so this will not work   $sql = "SELECT age, name, sex, desc FROM info";

Comment: Thats because `desc` is a reserved word. So change the column name OR put these column names you should not have used in backticks i.e. `SELECT \`desc\` FROM table` when using them in a query

Comment: @nbgoku, this is why it's important to always ask about your _actual_ question, not something you think might be its solution.

Comment: Thanks Riggs, works perfect! How do I vote for an answer?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_backticks